# SonarQube analysis is failing with the error server-wide lines of code total to exceed your 500000

Tags: sonarqube

We are using the developer edition of SonarQube 9.2. Our license details are like below

[image]

Our code analysis is failing with the below error

```
{"task":{"id":"AYFL9d206YvWba2a7DkU","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AX1SjmUGgaicIN43lF-5","componentKey":"Spotnana-Tech_spotnana","componentName":"spotnana-parent","componentQualifier":"TRK","status":"FAILED","submittedAt":"2022-06-10T04:53:35+0000","submitterLogin":"admin","startedAt":"2022-06-10T04:53:36+0000","executedAt":"2022-06-10T04:54:59+0000","executionTimeMs":83049,"errorMessage":"The last analysis failed because it would have caused your server-wide lines of code total to exceed your 500000 limit.","hasScannerContext":true,"branch":"master","branchType":"BRANCH","errorType":"LICENSING_LOC","warningCount":1,"warnings":[]}}
```

In sonar, I can see our current lines of code are only 230K

Can someone let us know how can we know what is going wrong and why the analysis has stopped?

[image]

Comment: Did the project key change? Or is this a different branch? It looks like Sonar thinks this is a new project, adding 231k to 279k is indeed more than 500k. Did [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/server-wide-lines-of-code-total-to-exceed-your-250000-limit/46099) or [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/getting-an-exceed-your-1000000-limit-license-error-when-trying-to-do-analysis/34676) question help you in any way?